# What is the difference between xerces-c_3_1.dll and xerces-c_3_1D.dll in Apache Xerces pre-built binaries?

Tags: c++, xerces, xerces-c

What is the difference between xerces-c_3_1.dll and xerces-c_3_1D.dll in apache xerces pre-built windows binaries (xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-windows-vc-9.0.zip from http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/download.cgi)?

(Similarly there is also xerces-c_3.lib vs xerces-c_3D.lib)

I assume it has to do with different xerces build options, but I can't seem to find any documentation describing the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builds with the D suffix are debug builds. From the [build instructions](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/build-3.html):

> When building your own applications you need to make sure that you are
>   linking your application with the xerces-c_3.lib (Release) and/or
>   xerces-c_3D.lib (Debug) libraries (or the static versions of them) and
>   also that the associated DLLs are somewhere in the executable/DLL
>   search path (PATH).